# Baixar texto de um textarea como arquivo sem linguagem server-side

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Preciso que ao usuário clicar num botão seja realizado o download do texto que está **dentro** do *textarea* como um arquivo JSON, por exemplo:

Usuário clica no botão <kbd>baixar</kbd> -> Começa download do arquivo `textarea.json`

Um exemplo que expressa melhor:

```
downloadFile(document.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML);
```

Onde eu apenas preciso que seja realizado o download do código contido no primeiro parâmetro.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor a relação entre arquivo/textarea e JSON?

Comment: Talvez seja melhor incluir o seu código atual, tanto envolvendo a textarea quanto o JSON esperado.

Comment: *"leiam com atenção"*... O quê, as duas linhas de explicação? Vi o resumo na página principal e abri a pergunta esperando pelo menos uns 4 paragrafos...

Comment: Desculpe, mas realmente é difícil de entender tentei explicar para alguns e eles não entenderam... É o seguinte: eu já tenho o código que gera o texto JSON que está na textarea só preciso realizar o download dele como um arquivo .json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não existe maneira ideal de fazer isso só no lado do cliente. Nos [browsers que suportam data URIs](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri), você pode fazer assim:

```
function downloadFile(conteudo) {
    window.location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(conteudo);
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ha2Wn/)</sup>

O problema disso é que o browser vai decidir o nome do arquivo que será baixado. Tem uma gambiarra pra isso, mas só vai funcionar em [browsers que suportam o atributo `download` em âncoras](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download):

```
function downloadFile(conteudo, filename) {
    var ancora = document.createElement('a');
    ancora.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(conteudo);
    ancora.download = filename;
    ancora.click();
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ELg96/)</sup>

Se quiser uma solução sem problemas de compatibilidade, passe o conteúdo para o servidor e force o download a partir de lá.