# Como fazer download de arquivo sem back-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, front-end

Quero forçar o download de um arquivo e estou tentando dessas duas maneiras.

**baixando na mesma página:**

```
  var docLocation = window.location.href + 'docs/apresentacao.pdf';
  var iframe = $('<iframe src="' + docLocation + '" class="hidden"></iframe>');

  $('body').append(iframe);
```

**dessa maneira o browser tenta interpretar o arquivo e retorna a mensagem:*

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Vi em algum lugar dizendo para converter o MIME type para `application/octet-stream` com uma linguagem back-end e isso forçaria o download.

**baixando em nova janela:**

```
  window.open(docLocation, '_blank');
```

O problema desse método é que ele abre o arquivo em uma nova janela (pop-up), e como os navegadores bloqueam pop-ups por padrão, o usuário teria que permitir o carregamento dessa janela o que acabaria fazendo com que alguns usuários não vissem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser deixar separado em uma função:

```
function download(uri, nome) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = nome;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: Achei interessante a solução, mas a [compatibilidade de navegadores](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) é baixa. Só funciona com browsers modernos, principalmente no caso do Safari para iOS.

Comment: Acho que seu código poderia ser melhorado, porque ele depende que o nome seja passado por parâmetro e no caso disso não acontecer, o nome do arquivo ficaria como 'undefined.ext'

Comment: Pesquisa prévia para evitar duplicatas é fundamental para a comunidade: >>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15842/3635 e >>>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13580/3635

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer assim, se percebi bem, usando o atributo [`download`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp):

```html
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" download>download</a>
```

No teu caso ficaria:

```
<a href="http://CAMINHO/PARA/docs/apresentacao.pdf" download>download pdf</a>
```

Para detetares se este atributo é compatível com o browser podes usar [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) e crias um elemento `a` para verificares:

```js
if("download" in document.createElement("a")) {
    alert('É compatível');
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112844/how-to-detect-support-for-the-html5-download-attribute)
[Compatibilidades](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)
[Outra Forma](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/quick-tip-using-the-html5-download-attribute--cms-23880)

Comment: Sempre achei a solução do atributo download perfeita pra esses casos, porém fica o problema do suporte a alguns browser. O ideal seria criar um servlet.

Comment: Se não for compatível, podes fazer uma função que por ex, dê um alert a dizer "Clique com o botão direito para fazer o download do ficheiro", @Matheus

Comment: Pesquisa prévia para evitar duplicatas é fundamental para a comunidade: >>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15842/3635 e >>>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13580/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento desculpa, realmente não reparei, confesso que não tenho o hábito ainda. Vou estar mais atento a isso

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a seguinte TAG HTML5:

```
<a href="your_link" download> file_name </a>
```

Porém a mesma não funciona em todos os navegadores. Segue a documentação da mesma do [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) para conseguir identificar os navegadores compatíveis.

Comment: Pesquisa prévia para evitar duplicatas é fundamental para a comunidade: >>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15842/3635 e >>>>>>>>>>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13580/3635